# Java Linux Printing Blank Page from PrinterJob

Tags: java, linux, printing

I have an app developed on a Mac (OS X, el capitan) using Java 8 (1.8.0_45) that prints to a printer. It prints to the printer perfectly well, drawing a nice circle (oval) on the paper. However, I have moved the app to a Linux Mint system (version 17.3, Mate) and it generates (ejects) a blank page. The same network printer is used for both (Brother MFC-J6510DW). I have installed proper drivers on the Linux system and can print just fine from the text editor or sending the Test Page. On the Linux system Java 7 is used (1.7.0_111). I am using Eclipse as my IDE on both the Mac and the Linux systems.

I have also successfully printed text with the app using the Mac, however again nothing but a blank page comes out of the printer on the Linux system. I tried the oval to eliminate and font issues between Mac and Linux.

I have already added code to check Printer Services and it is correctly finding the printer on the linux system. The dialog box for job.printDialog comes up (just like it does on the Mac system). Interestingly, the dialog box that comes up on the Linux system is a simplified version of the one that comes up on the Linux System when printing from the text editor. But still, it is a useful dialog box where I can even print to a file (which also generates a blank image).

I have searched online for answers, but have found nothing that seems to connect with this problem. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class PrintSomething  implements Printable, ActionListener {

public PrintSomething()
{

}

public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException
{   
    System.out.println("ENTERING PRINT JOB.  PAGE = " + page);

    if (page > 0)
    {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    System.out.println("Drawing Oval    PAGE = " + page);
    g2d.drawOval(50, 200, 50, 50);

 // g.drawString(“Hello World", 250, 50);

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(this);
    boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();

    if (doPrint)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("STARTING PRINT JOB");
            job.print();
        }
        catch (PrinterException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR in PRINT JOB");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the following does not specifically address the issue, here is what I found out and how I worked around the issue.

On a different system which has Linux Ubuntu 16.04 on it, I installed the same printer drivers and then ran the app there. It worked correctly, printing to the paper as expected.

The workaround was to trash the Linux Mint 17.3 on the system that had the issue and install Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Then I installed the printer drivers and tested the app. It worked as it should. So, for me, the problem is solved and I am moving on from it.

Thanks.